# Access nodeport service on microk8s on multipass vm on a ubuntu machine from other machines on the same LAN

Tags: microk8s

I set up 3 multipass vms on a local ubuntu machine on my home LAN, created a microk8s cluster with those vms.

If I run a web app on ubuntu (no vm, no k8s) then I can access the web app from my Windows laptop.

I want to access the web app (nodeport service) running on microk8s on those vms but it seems not a simple job.

Can I get a step by step instruction for the configuration?

Thanks in advance.